# Sorting results by 'order' in google app engine causing an error

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a property in GAE model, which is of DATETIME type. When I try to sort the results of a query by this property, the following error is raised:

`TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class`

Here is my query :

```
data_query = db.Query(docket).filter('last_update_date >', date).order('-last_update_date')
```

Comment: If it is really just a property, and not a database field, then neither filtering nor ordering will work.

Comment: Is `docket` your model that extends `db.Model`?

Comment: On a separate note, unless you have an absolute need for it, look into moving on to [ndb](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/) instead of the old `db`.

Comment: @mawimawi , filtering is working perfectly fine.

Comment: @Tomasz Łazarowicz , yes docket is the model and it extends db.Model , and yes i am planning to move to the ndb

Comment: @omair_77, I managed to reproduce your problem when I supplied an **instance** of the `db.Model` derived class to `db.Query`. Are you absolutely sure `docket` is the class, and not an instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`db.Query` expects a **class** to be supplied as its first argument (or *model_class* keyword argument).

```
class Query (model_class=None, ...)
    model_class
        Model (or Expando) class representing the entity kind
        to which the query applies.
```

[Source](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass#Query)

I managed to reproduce your problem when I supplied an **instance** of the `db.Model` derived class (an *entity*) to `db.Query`. Try replacing `docket` with the class or `docket.__class__`.

The exception occurs when `db.Query.order` method attempts to test whether *model_class* is a subclass of `db.Expando`. Since it uses the built-in Python function of [issubclass](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#issubclass), it requires its argument to be a class. Filtering works because `db.Query.filter` makes no such attempt to establish whether your Model extends `db.Expando`.